# Error in attempt to blockui (and unblockui) on ajaxStart/Complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-blockui

This is my first project and I am attempting to have the blockui fire when the application hits up the server for information. I looked up a few examples and thought my attempt below would work, but I was wrong.

```
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $.blockUI({
            css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .5,
                color: '#fff'
            }
        });


        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            $.unblockUI()
        });
```

Comment: Did you mean to forget `});` to close the `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){` part? You close the `$.blockUI({` call at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your full code, you forgot a `});` for the `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){` handler:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $.blockUI({
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
        }
    });
});   // <----- HERE


$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $.unblockUI()
});
```

Comment: Well, now don't I feel stupid? Oversight on my part, sorry. Thanks. HOWEVER, it is loading on the ajaxStart now, however it is not stopping on the completion. Do I have to set a timeout? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Lorenzo Don't worry, it happens to everyone. No you don't need to set a timeout though. From the blockUI documentation, they seem to use `$(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);`, which wouldn't be much different from this, but might be something to use instead of how you use the `ajaxComplete` call. Also, don't accept my answer until we figure this all out for you :)

Comment: It all works now. I didn't have the "()" after my `"$unblockUI"` (as I do above). Fixed it and it's all working fine. Thanks again for your help. Sometimes you've just been staring at the screen too long and it's nice to have a fresh pair of eyes to assist. Cheers. :)

Comment: @Lorenzo No problem. But exactly, that's what this place is for sometimes :)

Comment: @Lorenzo And you might want to use `ajaxStop` instead of `ajaxComplete`, because it waits for all open AJAX requests to complete. For example, if you fired off 5 AJAX requests at once, they'll come back at different times. If you use `ajaxComplete`, the `$.unblockUI()` will execute after the **first** one completes. If you use `ajaxStop`, the `$.unblockUI()` will execute after the **last** one completes. It's up to you and your design :)

Comment: oh, interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks! I will change it over.